# How can I subscribe and cast SourceList.Count to IObservable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, dynamic-data, reactiveui

I create ValidatableModelBase class and have some troubles. I need subscribe to SourceCache changes and cast Count collection to IObservable bool . How can i do it?

```
private readonly SourceCache<ValidationResult, string> _results;

public IObservalbe<bool> IsValid { get; }

public ValidatableModelBase()
{
    _results = new SourceCach<ValidationResult, string>(x => x.PropertyName);

    //Doesn't work. I think because i dont .Subscribe() to changes?
    IsValid = _results.Connect().IsEmpty();
}
```

upd:

```
HasErrors = collection.CountChanged.Subscribe(x => {Count = x;});
IsValid = this.WhenAnyValie(x => x.HasErrors).Select(x => x == 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```cs
var databasesValid = collectionOfReactiveObjects
    .Connect().Count().Select(x => x == 0);

// Then you can convert that IObservable<bool> to a view model
// property declared as ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool>.
_databasesValid = databasesValid.ToProperty(this, x => x.DatabasesValid);
```

You'll need to include the `DynamicData.Aggregation` namespace.

See https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData/blob/63960b0fa7bd0362c40e137498cd0014ba02f3dc/src/DynamicData/Aggregation/CountEx.cs#L57 here for code reference.

Comment: `.Count()` only returns a value when the underlying observable ends. You get a single value out that lets you know how many values the sequence produced before completing.

Comment: I suspect that it will be more like `.Connect().Select(x => x.Count()).Where(x => x == 0)` but I can't test this to be sure. Can you test?

Comment: `ISourceCache` happens to expose an `IObservable<bool>` property called CountChanged. Here are some unit tests to show usage: https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData/blob/63960b0fa7bd0362c40e137498cd0014ba02f3dc/src/DynamicData.Tests/Cache/SourceCacheFixture.cs#L99

Comment: Colt Bauman, thanks!


`HasErrors = collection.CountChanged.Subscribe(x => {Count = x;});
IsValid = this.WhenAnyValie(x => x.Count).Select(x => x == 0);`

Comment: @enigmativity using the dynamic data aggregation operator not the Rx extension. https://github.com/reactiveui/dynamicdata#aggregation this solution should work above.

Comment: @GlennWatson - Fair enough, but gee, that's confusing having multiple extension methods with the same name but different semantics.